# registering a dynamic bean with injection point in custom extension throws unsatisfied dependencies exception in cdi container bean validation phase

Tags: cdi

i am trying to write a cdi extension that registers a custom bean that himself has a injection of a managed bean.
When deploying application to payara server i got error message:

```
  Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ClassicTestBean with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private cditest.DynamicTestBean.bean
  at cditest.DynamicTestBean.bean(DynamicTestBean.java:0)
 -- WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ClassicTestBean with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private cditest.DynamicTestBean.bean
  at cditest.DynamicTestBean.bean(DynamicTestBean.java:0)
```

My code is as follows:

```
public class TestExtension implements Extension {
    public void lookupBeans(@Observes AfterBeanDiscovery  event, BeanManager bm) {
        event.addBean()
            .read(bm.createAnnotatedType(DynamicTestBean.class))
            .beanClass(DynamicTestBean.class)
            .scope(ApplicationScoped.class);
    }
}

public class DynamicTestBean {
    @Inject
    private ClassicTestBean bean;

    public void doSomething() {
        bean.doSomething();
    }
}

@Dependent
public class ClassicTestBean {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("test bean do");
    }
}

@Singleton
@Startup
public class TestStartup {

    @Inject
    private DynamicTestBean target;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        target.doSomething();
    }
}
```

file beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

The CDI container is not able to resolve dependency for injection of ClassicTestBean in class DynamicTestBean.

What i have tried to resolve problem without success:

- added @Default annotation to ClassicTestBean
- when i drop injection by replacing "@Inject private ClassicTestBean bean" to "private ClassicTestBean bean = new ClassicTestBean()" the sample application works. So registering DynamicTestBean is working.
- when i added @ApplicationScoped to class DynamicTestBean and dropped registering in Extension the sample works. I think problem is related to registering the bean in my Extension.
- when i register the ClassicTestBean dynamically like the DynamicTestBean the application is working:

```
public class ClassicTestBean {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("test bean do");
    }
} 
public class TestExtension implements Extension {
    public void lookupBeans(@Observes AfterBeanDiscovery  event, BeanManager bm) {
        event.addBean()
        .read(bm.createAnnotatedType(ClassicTestBean.class))
        .beanClass(ClassicTestBean.class);

        event.addBean()
            .read(bm.createAnnotatedType(DynamicTestBean.class))
            .beanClass(DynamicTestBean.class)
            .scope(ApplicationScoped.class);
    }
}
```

I seems that beans that are not registered by the Extension class are not resolvable for injection into beans that are dynamically registered by the Extension.
I cannot find any hint in the cdi spec doc or weld doc that explains this behavier.

Anyone here who could help me? Thank you all in advance!